# \cellcolor is taking too much space in a matrix

Tags: color, matrices

I would like to highlight a row, a column and a specific cell in a matrix. I ended up using `\cellcolor`. My problem is that `\cellcolor` is taking too much space, therefore the matrix borders are being covered by the color. As you see in the below picture how the matrix is ruined by the color

[image]

and this is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cellcolor{green} ss &  \cellcolor{red!80} ss \\
\cellcolor{green} ss &  \cellcolor{red!80} ss \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you may be better off using a traditional `array` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left[\,\begin{array}{cc}
    \cellcolor{green} ss &  \cellcolor{red!80} ss \\
    \cellcolor{green} ss &  \cellcolor{red!80} ss \\
  \end{array}\,\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

If all the cells belonging to the same columns have the same color, with `array` you can specify the color of the column directly, without resorting to `\cellcolor` for each cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left[\,
  \begin{array}{>{\columncolor{green}}c >{\columncolor{red!80}}c}
     ss &  ss \\
     ss &  ss \\
  \end{array}\,
  \right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]